# Exercicio de matriz da faculdade

Tags: c

Fala ai, pessoal. É meu primeiro post aqui então foi mal se tiver algum erro.
Eu comecei a fazer facul de ADS a pouco tempo e to com muita dificuldade em um exercício de Matriz em linguagem C.
O Exercício é o seguinte:

1. Faça um programa que, dada uma matriz quadrada de ordem 3 gere:
   a. Matriz identidade
   b. Matriz com todos os elementos iguais a 1"
   Esse foi o máximo que consegui pensar, depois disso não me vem nada a cabeça pra tentar efetuar o que é pedido no exercício.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: [Que erro eu cometi fazendo minha pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8388/que-erro-eu-cometi-fazendo-minha-pergunta)

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta descrevendo melhor em qual passo está com dúvida (e imagens não devem ser usadas para código). Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e depois o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Comment: Se é para gerar matrizes como pedido em (a) e (b) então não precisa fazer nenhuma leitura, basta atribuir ou 0 ou 1 a cada elemento da matriz.